# Your first extension - official Firefox extension tutorial not working

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-sdk, firefox-addon-webextensions

I wanted to try learning how to make a browser extension and tried doing the first official tutorial https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Your_first_WebExtension

When following everything here and going into a mozilla.org domain the extension does not put a red border around the site. It basically does nothing. (I know that content scripts are disabled on addon.mozilla.org)

I've carefully followed each step of the tutorial.

Here's the repository for the tutorial : https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/master/borderify

I just want to verify if I'm the only one with who this tutorial does not work.

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial is fine. You can try changing it to another site and test again. For example:

```
{

  "description": "Adds a solid red border to all webpages matching mozilla.org. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Examples#borderify",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Borderify",
  "version": "1.0",
  "homepage_url": "https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/master/borderify",
  "icons": {
    "48": "icons/border-48.png"
  },

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*.example.com/*"],
      "js": ["borderify.js"]
    }
  ]

}
```

Then go to `https://example.com/` to test.

Comment: It does not work. I've been loading the extension by using the load temporary addon in about:debugging. Would you have any idea of why it doesn't work for me?

Comment: @Nassims I have tested the same extension loaded temporarily with `"matches": ["*://*.example.com/*"]` now and it works fine. Click on INSPECT and check if there are any errors.

Comment: It does nothing and there is no error as well in the console.

Comment: @Nassims then there is an error somewhere. Do yo pack the extension into xpi or use the unpacked and open the `manifest.json` from load temporary addon in about:debugging?

Comment: I use the unpacked and open manifest.json from load temporary addon in about:debugging.

Comment: Is there any error logged to console `Ctrl+Shift+j` when you instal? Which version of Firefox is it?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem: the **Borderify** example was not working. In my case, it was a problem of my default browser's privacy settings.

Try going to Firefox settings and see if the option **Always use private mode** is disabled.

Alternatively, after loading the extension in debugging mode, go to the **Add-Ons** section and **enable the extension for private windows**.

Answer (score 0):

Zip the files before adding to Load Temporary Add-on.

There is a **STEP**, "Your First Extension - Official Firefox Extension" **Tutorial Missing**...

That you need to make a **ZIP file** from extension files,
Like this

```
my_extension.zip
  |- borderify.js
  |- manifest.json
  |- icons
```

**Missing STEP Link-** 
https://extensionworkshop.com/documentation/publish/package-your-extension/